# Error in Bash Script Nested Conditional Statements

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting

Getting the error below as I'm sure my syntax is off somehow with the nested conditionals. Basically I don't want to send an empty message to my telegram_bot which throws an error if it detects empty message. The first IF just detects if its NULL which works. But the case on line 32 doesnt.

```
xxx.sh: line 32: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
xxx.sh: line 32: `    *)       # contains nothing or only spaces'


 26 if  [ -z "$message" ]; then
 27         echo "Please pipe a message to me!"
 28 else
 29   case $message in
 30     *[!\ ]*) # contains non-space
 31         sendTelegram                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
 32     *)       # contains nothing or only spaces
 33         DO NOTHING...
 34   esac
 35 fi
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to terminate your case clauses:

```
case $message in
    *[!\ ]*) # contains non-space
        sendTelegram
    ;;                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    *)       # contains nothing or only spaces
        DO NOTHING..
    ;;
esac
```

[Conditional Constructs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Conditional-Constructs)

> Each clause must be terminated with `;;`, `;&`, or `;;&`.
>
> If the `;;` operator is used, no subsequent matches are attempted after the first pattern match. Using `;&` in place of `;;` causes execution to continue with the command-list associated with the next clause, if any. Using `;;&` in place of `;;` causes the shell to test the patterns in the next clause, if any, and execute any associated command-list on a successful match.

---

As Kusalananda points out you can actually skip the terminator in the last clause if you so desire.

Comment: The `;;` is not needed in the last branch.

Comment: @Kusalananda: TIL.  I have always included it though, I don't think it should cause any issues, no?

Comment: No, there's nothing _wrong_ with including it. It's just optional at the very end.

Comment: @ilkkachu POSIX grammar it is.

Comment: can i just leave my lines 32 and 33 out completely since I just want it to do nothing anyways?

Comment: @Patoshiパトシ: You can, it will only execute the code in a clause if there is a match, otherwise the case will just end